# FSCalendar - I want to select date on longPressGesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, github, calendar

How to select date using LongpressGesture using FSCalendar??

I am using [WenchaoD/FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) third party calendar from github.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDate *selectedDate = [self.calculator dateForIndexPath:indexPath];
    FSCalendarMonthPosition monthPosition = [self.calculator monthPositionForIndexPath:indexPath];
    FSCalendarCell *cell;
    if (monthPosition == FSCalendarMonthPositionCurrent) {
        cell = (FSCalendarCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [self cellForDate:selectedDate atMonthPosition:FSCalendarMonthPositionCurrent];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
        if (indexPath) {
            [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
        }
    }
    if (![_selectedDates containsObject:selectedDate]) {
        cell.selected = YES;
        [cell performSelecting];
    }
    [self enqueueSelectedDate:selectedDate];
    [self.delegateProxy calendar:self didSelectDate:selectedDate atMonthPosition:monthPosition];
    [self selectCounterpartDate:selectedDate];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold and multiple selection:

```
yourCalendarObject.swipeToChooseGesture.enabled = YES;
yourCalendarObject.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Hold and single selection:

```
[yourCalendarObject setAllowsSelection: YES];
[yourCalendarObject setAllowsMultipleSelection: NO];
yourCalendarObject.swipeToChooseGesture.enabled = YES;
```

EDIT: to difference the tap or hold action FSCalendar doesn't have that functionality but you can add with a single property.

**FSCalendar.h**

You need to add this property in your header file inside of:

```
@interface FSCalendar : UIView

/**
Difference the tap or hold gesture date selection
When the value = YES is a UILongPressGestureRecognizer
When the value = NO is a tap selection
*/

@property (readonly, nonatomic) BOOL isLongPressGesture;

@end
```

**FSCalendar.m**

You need to add a set value of property in **- (void)handleSwipeToChoose:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)pressGesture** like this:

```
- (void)handleSwipeToChoose:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)pressGesture
{
    switch (pressGesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

            // New property value when the selection is UILongPressGestureRecognizer
            _isLongPressGesture = YES; 

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[pressGesture locationInView:self.collectionView]];
            if (indexPath && ![indexPath isEqual:self.lastPressedIndexPath]) {
                NSDate *date = [self.calculator dateForIndexPath:indexPath];
                FSCalendarMonthPosition monthPosition = [self.calculator monthPositionForIndexPath:indexPath];
                if (![self.selectedDates containsObject:date] && [self collectionView:self.collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]) {
                    [self selectDate:date scrollToDate:NO atMonthPosition:monthPosition];
                    [self collectionView:self.collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                } else if (self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection && [self collectionView:self.collectionView shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]) {
                    [self deselectDate:date];
                    [self collectionView:self.collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                }
            }
            self.lastPressedIndexPath = indexPath;
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled: {
            self.lastPressedIndexPath = nil;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Well you need to modify the method **- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** like this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDate *selectedDate = [self.calculator dateForIndexPath:indexPath];
    FSCalendarMonthPosition monthPosition = [self.calculator monthPositionForIndexPath:indexPath];
    FSCalendarCell *cell;
    if (monthPosition == FSCalendarMonthPositionCurrent) {
        cell = (FSCalendarCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [self cellForDate:selectedDate atMonthPosition:FSCalendarMonthPositionCurrent];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
        if (indexPath) {
            [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
        }
    }
    if (![_selectedDates containsObject:selectedDate]) {
        cell.selected = YES;
        [cell performSelecting];
    }
    [self enqueueSelectedDate:selectedDate];
    [self.delegateProxy calendar:self didSelectDate:selectedDate atMonthPosition:monthPosition];
    [self selectCounterpartDate:selectedDate];

    // Reset the value of property
    _isLongPressGesture = NO;
}
```

So you can try this:

```
- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date atMonthPosition:(FSCalendarMonthPosition)monthPosition
{
    if (calendar.isLongPressGesture)
        NSLog(@"Long Press");
    else
        NSLog(@"Tap Gesture");
}
```

Enjoy the code :)

Comment: Hello Dear, I don't want multiple selection, I want to display selected date on LongPressGuesture.

Comment: Thanks you so much @Ladd.c . . . it Works. can you do one more favor -> how to recognise holded selection and tapped selection?? - (BOOL)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar shouldSelectDate:(NSDate *)date atMonthPosition:(FSCalendarMonthPosition)monthPosition

Comment: Sorry for the delay, ok let me update my answer with that code :) PD: I'm updating to Xcode 10

Comment: Yes, I updated the code I put the full code of methods to not confuse nobody